# Redeclared without usage before and after a loop

Tags: python-3.6

I've declared a boolean variable  before a loop and redeclared it when the loop is complete to tell some functions inside the loop and in a following loop that need this information.

What is the correct way of doing it so that Pycharm doesnt give a warning?

before loop starts

bool_variable = False

for some variable in loop:

do something that needs to know if bool_variable is True or False

after loop finishes

bool_variable = True

Comment: can you explain in detail.

Comment: All the details are there. I dont know what else to provide. I should probably have the script split into separate files but just seeing if there is a way of avoiding this warning.

Comment: So,   here what do you really looking for.

Comment: Im wanting to know the correct way of approaching this so I dont get the redeclaration without usage error...

Comment: Anyone know a solution to this?